# NLP for preparing questions from the list of synonyms and antonyms

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers

I am aware of T5 Transformers based models that can convert text to FillinBlanks, Matching and MCQs. Most of them seem to be very vague and provide meaningless questions. If i provide curated list of synonyms and antonyms, can I train/fine-tune them and convert them in to question?

At present, I used something similar to:

```
def MCQs_available(word,s2v):
    word = word.replace(" ", "_")
    sense = s2v.get_best_sense(word)
    if sense is not None:
        return True
    else:
        return False




def sense2vec_get_words(word,s2v):
    output = []

    word_preprocessed =  word.translate(word.maketrans("","", string.punctuation))
    word_preprocessed = word_preprocessed.lower()

    word_edits = edits(word_preprocessed)

    word = word.replace(" ", "_")

    sense = s2v.get_best_sense(word)
    most_similar = s2v.most_similar(sense, n=15)

    compare_list = [word_preprocessed]
    for each_word in most_similar:
        append_word = each_word[0].split("|")[0].replace("_", " ")
        append_word = append_word.strip()
        append_word_processed = append_word.lower()
        append_word_processed = append_word_processed.translate(append_word_processed.maketrans("","", string.punctuation))
        if append_word_processed not in compare_list and word_preprocessed not in append_word_processed and append_word_processed not in word_edits:
            output.append(append_word.title())
            compare_list.append(append_word_processed)


    out = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(output))

    return out

def get_options(answer,s2v):
    distractors =[]

    try:
        distractors = sense2vec_get_words(answer,s2v)
        if len(distractors) > 0:
            print(" Sense2vec_distractors successful for word : ", answer)
            return distractors,"sense2vec"
    except:
        print (" Sense2vec_distractors failed for word : ",answer)


    return distractors,"None"

def tokenize_sentences(text):
    sentences = [sent_tokenize(text)]
    sentences = [y for x in sentences for y in x]
    # Remove any short sentences less than 20 letters.
    sentences = [sentence.strip() for sentence in sentences if len(sentence) > 20]
    return sentences
```

Is it possible if i provide curated set of list of synonyms and antonyms and it will train and frame questions?